# Node JS express JS app User not getting redirected

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, cookies, https

Whenever I try and redirect the user to the dashboard, the server receives the get request to the dashboard page but the user's page does not get redirected. It remains on the login page, the cookie is received by the user.

This is the login function that sends the session key cookie and the redirection to the dashboard.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({'email' : email}, function(err, user){
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if (user)
        {
            var hash = user.password;
            if (passwordManagement.verifyPassword(password, hash))
            {
                var newSession = webSession.generateKey(email)
                webSession.SessionKeys.push(newSession);
                
                res.cookie('session', newSession.key);
                return res.redirect(303, '/dashboard');
            }
            else
            {
                res.cookie('session', 'logErr');
                return res.redirect(303, '/login');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            res.cookie('session', 'logErr');
            return res.redirect(303, '/login');
        }
    })
});
```

This is the dashboard call that should occur when the user is redirected from the login POST method.

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){
    var sessionKey = req.cookies.session
    if (sessionKey != undefined)
    {
        var email = webSession.findEmailFromSessionKey(sessionKey);
        if (email)
        {
            User.findOne({'email' : email}, function(err, user){
                if (err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                if (user)
                {
                    fs.readFile(process.cwd() + '/Web Pages/Public/Logged/Dashboard.html', 'utf8', function(err, data){
                        if (err) {console.log('FS READ Dashboard Error:\n' + err)}
                        else
                        {
                            data = webSession.generateDashboard(user, data);
                            fs.writeFile('temp.html', data, function(err){
                                if (err) {console.log('FS WRITE Dashboard Error:\n' + err)}
                                else
                                {
                                    console.log('Sending DASHBOARD file');
                                    res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/temp.html', function(err){
                                        if (err) {console.log('RES Dashboard Error:\n' + err)}
                                        else
                                        {
                                            fs.unlink(process.cwd() + '/temp.html', function(err){
                                                if (err) {console.log('FS UNLINK Dashboard Error:\n' + err)};
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    res.cookie('session', '');
                    return res.redirect('/login');
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            res.cookie('session', '');
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        res.cookie('session', '');
        return res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please share the code for the `/dashboard` route as well.

Comment: This only works if you're using SSR, meaning you only use Node. If you use some kind of Ajax like fetch from browsers, you have to redirect from browsers